# Как реализовать такую тень при помощи градиента

Tags: html, css, градиент, linear-gradient

Это box-shadow, наложенный на градиент или градиент в чистом виде? Как его реализовать?
[image: Тень]

Comment: а если под низ подсунуть div с градиентом и размыть его или псевдоэлемент с такими же эффектами ?

Comment: Можно сделать наложением box-shadow на :before и :after и сместить их немного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдоэлемент с линейным градиентом и размытием решает задачу. Главное, задать наклон градиенту.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 370px; width: 580px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #f3f3f3, #bebebe);
  filter: blur(7px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```